# Change the border color if input value is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to do is change the color of ALL the input text borders at the same time if it/they have null or no value upon clicking the button, I have a function to do this.
First I put the input text that I want to check the values into an array, then call the function where in it loops through the array and check for the null values. On button click, if all of my input text are null it will only change the color of the first index in the array.

Here is my function:

```
function isValid(array){
            for(var x=0;x<array.length;x++){
                if (array[x].value.trim() == ""){
                    $(array[x]).css("border-color","#FF0000");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how I call my function:

```
var array = [document.getElementById('txtLastName'),
            document.getElementById('txtFirstName')
            ];
if (!isValid1(array)) {
return false;
    }
```

How to change the border color of all the input in the array with null values?
Thanks!

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: How to change the border color of all the input in the array with null values

Comment: change for(var x=0;x<=array.length;x++){} in loop

Comment: You will never want to access array[2] when there are only 2 elements in the array.. It is gonna throw an error if you change the loop to x <= array.length

Comment: `$(array[x]).css("border-color","#FF0000");` - since you're using jquery, why don't you use `$('input').each( ...`?

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya thanks! but I don't think that is the issue. The first element of an array is actually at index 0, and array length is 2(if based on my given example).

Comment: Its work for me exactly you want. !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my two cent, may need tuning:

```
function isValid(selector){
    return ($(selector).filter(function() {
        return (this.value.trim() === "");
    }).css("border-color","#FF0000").length === 0);
}
```

To use it:

```
isValid("#txtLastName, #txtFirstName");
```

I build the CSS selector in caller and pass it to `isValid()`, you could have passed the array `["txtFirstName", "txtFirstName"]` and build the selector in `isValid()`.

There are many ways to do this, a more modular approach is to use a `nullValidate` class as selector, so you can have as many validated field as you like.

**EDIT:** return if invalid elements are found

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to return false if there is a null values. where could I add that?

Comment: What do you mean by null values? `<input>` values have a default of `""` (or the value specified in `value` attribute) and will not be `null`.

Comment: Or you wanted the function to help track if there is any empty value? I've made edit, you can check the truthiness of `isValid()` return.

Answer (score 0):

Why a mix of jQuery and vanilla JS .. Can just use `filter` method.

```
$('#txtLastName, #txtFirstName').filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value) === '';
}).css("border-color","#FF0000");
```

**Also there is nothing wrong with the way you have written the code.**

You must have not been using the correct id most probably.

[**Your Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/g6szN/)

**[JQuery Code](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/g6szN/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents worth

```
<form name="form">
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
<input type="button" name="submit_btn" value="send" />
</form>


$(document).ready(function(){

$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
    var length = $('input[type="text"]').val().length;
    if(length===0){
        $(this).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
    }
    else {
        $(this).css({"border": ""});
    }
});

$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
   var length = $('input[type="text"]').val().length;
    if(length===0){
        $('input[type="text"]').css({"border":"1px solid red"});
    } else {
        $('input[type="text"]').css({"border":""});
    }
});
```

});